# MS Access- monthly, identify first time customers, second and third consecutive customers

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am building a database in Access 2007 that will capture customer returns monthly in three ways: first time customer has returned an item, second consecutive month of a return and third consecutive month.

Data is in tblActions and has fields UniqueID (Customer Name), Reporting Month (end of month date), Reference (Primary key).

Currently, I am using:

```
SELECT tblActions.[Unique ID], tblActions.[Reporting Month], tblActions.Reference
FROM tblActions
WHERE (((tblActions.[Reporting Month]) Between Date() And DateAdd("m",-3,Date())));
```

This shows me all customers with returns in the last three months, I need to filter out any that appear only once in three months, or twice, etc...

Notes: The customer data is imported once per month from a report;
I can change the format of the Reporting Month field if it will help.

Thank you for any ideas.

Melissa

Comment: How about a crosstab?

Comment: Nice idea, I see how this makes it easy to see what I am looking for. I was hoping to use the results as a record source for a form that a user can add additional information to for each record. I am going to play with this idea. Thank you very much, Fionnuala

Comment: You may like to play around with http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs,_forms_and_updating, or you may consider just opening a new form for editing.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT tblActions.[Unique ID], Count(tblActions.[Unique ID]) AS [CountOfUnique ID]
FROM tblActions
WHERE (((tblActions.[Reporting Month]) Between Date() And DateAdd("m",-3,Date())))
GROUP BY tblActions.[Unique ID]
HAVING (((Count(tblActions.[Unique ID]))=3));